# How to get formcollection using ajax.actionlink

Tags: ajax, actionlink, formcollection

I have a controller with the codes like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    //why is that the collection is null?
}
```

I am calling this action using the ajax.actionlink.

my problem is the collection is null, unlike if i use the submit(input) button
the formcollection has values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection.aspx) has a default binder associated with it which always initializes the collection and you should never get `null`. It is more likely that you have an empty collection when using Ajax.ActionLink in contrast to when using a form submit button. This is because the ActionLink method doesn't POST any form values when it performs the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Ajax.BeginForm`