# MVC Ajax.ActionLink doesn't find POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, routes, actionlink

I have a POST method declared in my controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UpdateComments(int id, string comments)
{
    // ... 
}
```

and an ActionLink in my view:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("update", "UpdateComments", 
                        new { id = Model.Id, comments = "test" }, 
                        new AjaxOptions { 
                                HttpMethod="POST", 
                                OnFailure="alert('fail');", 
                                OnSuccess = "alert('success');" 
                            })%>
```

I get a "not found" error when it tries to route this request.

If I remove the POST restriction from the UpdateComments method in the controller, it works fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems it didn't like the way I was declaring my `OnFailure` and `OnSuccess` callbacks. I guess it couldn't parse my `AjaxOptions` object so was ignoring the `HttpMethod="POST"` setting.

I got it working by changing it to:

```
OnFailure="function() { alert('fail'); }",
OnSuccess="function() { alert('success'); }"
```

Answer (score 4):

I am learning ASP.MVC at this moment and I had that issue with my Ajax.ActionLink, I got a GET method and not a POST method as it should had been. Then I realize that I didn't add the scripts library reference:

```
<script src=”/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
<script src=”/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>
```

After I adding the script it worked fine!

Comment: These are obsolete in MVC3 and MVC4. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8784998/210780

Answer (score 0):

> FormCollection has a default binder
>   associated with it which always
>   initializes the collection and you
>   should never get null. It is more
>   likely that you have an empty
>   collection when using Ajax.ActionLink
>   in contrast to when using a form
>   submit button. This is because the
>   ActionLink method doesn't POST any
>   form values when it performs the AJAX
>   request.
>   [This post is the unswer to you question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550219/how-to-get-formcollection-using-ajax-actionlink)

Answer (score 0):

try including

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you please elaborate on why this will help?  A large part of a good answer is not only understanding the solution, but understanding why things were a problem to begin with!

Comment: These are obsolete in MVC3 and MVC4. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8784998/210780